# Uniformly Lipschitz sets are bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis

*Let $\mathcal{F}\subset C([a,b],G)$   $(a,b\in \mathbb{R},G\subset \mathbb{R}^d)$ be uniformly Lipschitz continuous. Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous. Is such a set bounded in $C([a,b],G)$?*

I have already shown the first statement and I was hoping someone could help me with the question, if such a set is bounded? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Such a set does not need to be bounded. For example, let $\mathcal F$ be the set of all constant functions. This set is uniformly Lipschitz continuous but not bounded in $C([a,b],G)$.